Supabase RPC: SQL Injection and other security issues
I am working on a PL/pgSQL function that will be exposed to the public via RPC (supabase allows this). The critical thing about this function is that it gets the column name as a string, which will then be used in dynamic SQL.
Is there any way to improve this piece of code to prevent SQL injections and/or other security issues?
My main approach is checking whether the passed argument is in the valid domain of allowed column names.
create function top_100_by_criterion(criterion varchar)
returns table(id uuid, rank bigint, username text, value bigint) as
$$
declare
  valid_columns text[];
begin
  -- Populating allowed columns
  select array_agg(column_name::text)
  into valid_columns
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_name='leaderboard';

  -- If the parameter is not known, throw an error
  if not criterion = any (valid_columns) then
        raise exception 'Invalid criterion: %', criterion;
  end if;

  -- Use quote_ident to safely quote identifiers
  return query execute format(
    'select id, rank, username, %I
    from (
      select l.id, 
             dense_rank() over (order by %I desc) as rank, 
             p.username, 
             %I
      from leaderboard as l 
      inner join profiles as p on l.id = p.id
      order by rank, p.username
    ) as ranked_leader_board
    limit 100',
    criterion, criterion, criterion
  );
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

My main concern is that the "if" check could be passed, though I am not sure and need guidance here.
